# In Swift calculate color without transparency obtained by overlaying a color with an transparant color

Tags: swift, colors

[image: Colors overlaying]

- I have a original UIView that has a non transparant color `orgColor`.
- This is overlayed by an overlay UIView that has a `overlayColor` with transparancy (alpha channel).

Given those two colors `orgColor` and `overlayColor` how do I calculate the `calculatedColor` that should **not have any transparency** but is exactly the same color on screen then as if both views would actually be overlayed?

I have written a skeleton function for this (to show the principle). But don't know how the calculate (I found a couple of posts on stack overflow regarding color blending but none would actually remove the transparency in the result...):

```
func calculateColor(orgColor: UIColor, overlayColor: UIColor) -> UIColor {
    var (r1, g1, b1, a1) = (CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0))
    var (r2, g2, b2, a2) = (CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0))

    orgColor.getRed(&r1, green: &g1, blue: &b1, alpha: &a1)
    overlayColor.getRed(&r2, green: &g2, blue: &b2, alpha: &a2)

    //how to put the alpha in the r g b? and integrate the overlay r g b?

    return color
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alpha of the overlay color (`a2`) tells you the percentage that color contributes to the total, and `(1 - a2)` tells you the percentage the original color contributes.  From that, it is a straightforward calculation:

```
func calculateColor(orgColor: UIColor, overlayColor: UIColor) -> UIColor {
    // Helper function to clamp values to range (0.0 ... 1.0)
    func clampValue(_ v: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        guard v > 0 else { return  0 }
        guard v < 1 else { return  1 }
        return v
    }

    var (r1, g1, b1, a1) = (CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0))
    var (r2, g2, b2, a2) = (CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0))

    orgColor.getRed(&r1, green: &g1, blue: &b1, alpha: &a1)
    overlayColor.getRed(&r2, green: &g2, blue: &b2, alpha: &a2)

    // Make sure the input colors are well behaved
    // Components should be in the range (0.0 ... 1.0)
    r1 = clampValue(r1)
    g1 = clampValue(g1)
    b1 = clampValue(b1)

    r2 = clampValue(r2)
    g2 = clampValue(g2)
    b2 = clampValue(b2)
    a2 = clampValue(a2)

    let color = UIColor(  red: r1 * (1 - a2) + r2 * a2,
                        green: g1 * (1 - a2) + g2 * a2,
                         blue: b1 * (1 - a2) + b2 * a2,
                        alpha: 1)

    return color
}
```

Intuitively this checks out.  If the overlay color is fully opaque (`a2 == 1`) then the result will be the overlay color.  If the overlay color is fully transparent (`a2 == 0`), the result will be the original color.  If the overlay color's alpha is `0.5`, you will get a blend that is exactly halfway between the two colors.

---

**Testing it in a Playground:**

```
// Make these colors anything you want
let c1 = UIColor(red: 27/255, green: 155/255, blue: 199/255, alpha: 1.0)
let c2 = UIColor(red: 188/255, green: 13/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 0.37)

let c3 = calculateColor(orgColor: c1, overlayColor: c2)

let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

view1.backgroundColor = c1
view2.backgroundColor = c2

// Overlay view2 onto view1
view1.addSubview(view2)

// view3 has the calculated color
let view3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
view3.backgroundColor = c3

// display the views side by side in view4
let view4 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
view4.addSubview(view1)
view4.addSubview(view3)

// display this view and see that the two halves match
view4
```

**Playground output:**

[image: Playground output]

Comment: vacawama this works perfectly! Very nice formatted and complete answer as well. Just one remarks: in the color calculation should we not put in the values cannot get bigger then 1.0 (found this in other answers for other blending calculations) using the min (..., 1.0) function?

Comment: check the extension I wrote (all credit to you!), I put in the min function

Comment: The `min` is *not necessary* if the input values are in the range `0.0 ... 1.0` as they *should* be.  Even if `r1` is `1.0` and `r2` is `1.0` (their maximum values), the combination of `r1 * (1 - a2) + r2 * a2` will max out at `1.0` . That said, it is possible to create `UIColor`s with out of range values, and even though they are interpreted as clamped to that range, `UIColor.getRed(green:blue:alpha:)` will still return the out of range values.  To get correct results with these *bad* colors, it is necessary to clamp the ranges.  See the fix above.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @vacawama 's answer (all credit to him!) I wrote the following extension to UIColor:

```
extension UIColor {

    func solidColorWhenOverlayed(by overlayColor: UIColor) -> UIColor {
        // Helper function to clamp values to range (0.0 ... 1.0)
        func clampValue(_ v: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            guard v > 0 else { return  0 }
            guard v < 1 else { return  1 }
            return v
        }

        var (r1, g1, b1, a1) = (CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0))
        var (r2, g2, b2, a2) = (CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0))

        getRed(&r1, green: &g1, blue: &b1, alpha: &a1)
        overlayColor.getRed(&r2, green: &g2, blue: &b2, alpha: &a2)

        // Make sure the input colors are well behaved
        // Components should be in the range (0.0 ... 1.0)
        // This to compensate for any "bad" colors = colors which have component values out of range
        r1 = clampValue(r1)
        g1 = clampValue(g1)
        b1 = clampValue(b1)

        r2 = clampValue(r2)
        g2 = clampValue(g2)
        b2 = clampValue(b2)
        a2 = clampValue(a2)

        return UIColor(  red  : r1 * (1 - a2) + r2 * a2,
                         green: g1 * (1 - a2) + g2 * a2,
                         blue : b1 * (1 - a2) + b2 * a2,
                         alpha: 1)
    }

}
```

Comment: Style issue:  I would suggest `self.getRed` instead of `getRed` because it is much clearer what is happening.  See the clamp issue I raised above.  Your `min` solution will not help *bad* input colors.

Comment: I like the extension.  You might want to name it `solidColorWhenOverlayed(by overlayColor: UIColor)` which is more consistent with the less redundant style of Swift 3/4.