# NSAttributedString: How to mimic opacity or alpha equivalent using color

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsattributedstring, uicolor

I am using `NSAttributedString` for a button title and would like to be able to "grey out" or lower the alpha or capacity of certain text. `NSAttributedString` does not appear to allow you to modify the opacity or alpha value of the text but does let you adjust the color using:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text = 
 [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
   initWithAttributedString: label.attributedText];
[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
             value:[UIColor redColor] 
             range:NSMakeRange(10, 1)];
```

or:

```
let range = (mainString as NSString).range(of: stringToColor)
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: mainString)
mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: range)
```

In this case, the starting color is System Blue.  Is there any formula that would allow me to modify the system color to the equivalent of an alpha value (or opacity) of 0.5?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: When you fade a color by lowering the alpha, you mix it with the background color. This [Q and A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51679096/1630618) shows how you can compute the resulting mixed color..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change any color alpha using

```
UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Of course, you have to know the original color.

There is no universal alpha modifier.

Comment: So  value: UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5) or let myColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComonent(0.5) and then value: myColor? (I think I can get the system color with self.view.tintColor)